# Python Script Will Not Run In Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

When I installed sublime text 3 and python, I cannot build the script using ctrl+b. Python was installed in the C:/ directory. When reading online for similar issues the answers have said to go to Preferences>Browse Packages... and edit a file there. However, there are no files there when I go to the directory. Any help will be appreciated.

Error as follows:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Jordan McBride\Desktop\Python\helloWorld.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Jordan McBride\Desktop\Python]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\]
```

Comment: @taesu and how do i go about that?

Comment: search on google *how to add python to path windows*. google is your friend